# UITableViewCell disappears randomly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

so I making a chat page in my using socket io, I have 2 lables for incoming and outcoming messages.

I have a var called ChatText which will store the content like this :

> [["Hi, how are you? ", "0"], ["I am good, What about you?", "1"]]

Where 0 = sent and 1 = received

So I can know which one is the sent and the received messages and set them to the labels and style them

I dont know if this is the right way to do it or not , I searched in the internet couldn't find too much info so i just made it like this, please tell me if its wrong or tell me how to solve this issue.

this is my code I have so far where I think the problem must be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TableChatCell


    cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


    let ChatTextFixed = self.ChatText[indexPath.row] as NSArray
    if ChatTextFixed.count > 0 {
        if ChatTextFixed[1] as! Int == 0 {
            cell!.ChatLableS.text = ChatTextFixed[0] as? String
            cell!.RView.hidden = true
        }

        if ChatTextFixed[1] as! Int == 1  {
            cell!.ChatLableR.text = ChatTextFixed[0] as? String
            cell!.SView.hidden = true
        }
        print(ChatTextFixed)
    }

    cell!.ChatLableS.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell!.ChatLableR.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return cell!
}
```

NOTE: If I remove these If conditions :

```
if ChatTextFixed[1] as! Int == 0 {}
if ChatTextFixed[1] as! Int == ! {}
```

and set the text to 1 label only it works like this:

```
cell!.ChatLableS.text = ChatTextFixed[0] as? String
cell!.RView.hidden = true
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is because of

```
cell!.RView.hidden = true
cell!.SView.hidden = true
```

but how can i hide the other label and show only one!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! MyTableViewCell

    let ChatTextFixed = ChatText[indexPath.row]
    if let index = Int(ChatTextFixed[1]) where index == 0 {
        cell.ChatLableS.text = ChatTextFixed[0]
        cell.ChatLableR.hidden = true
        cell.RView.hidden = true
    } else {
        cell.ChatLableR.text = ChatTextFixed[0]
        cell.ChatLableS.hidden = true
        cell.SView.hidden = true
    }

    cell.ChatLableS.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.ChatLableR.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return cell
```

Comment: it works fine until that point , even tho i can put some new data but after 5+ messages when i scroll they start hiding or even when new data inserted they also get hidden.

Comment: I think the problem is reusable cell, try to hide all views and labels, then show each component in if else block

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but changing my code like this works :

```
       if ChatTextFixed[1] as! Int == 0 {
            cell!.ChatLableS.text = ChatTextFixed[0] as? String
            cell!.ChatLableR.text = ""
            cell!.RView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell!.SView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 69/225, green: 189/225, blue: 120/225, alpha: 1.0)
            //cell!.RView.hidden = true
        }

        if ChatTextFixed[1] as! Int == 1  {
            cell!.ChatLableR.text = ChatTextFixed[0] as? String
            cell!.ChatLableS.text = ""
            cell!.SView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell!.RView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 200/225, green: 200/225, blue: 200/225, alpha:1.0)
            //cell!.SView.hidden = true
        }
```

so I set the text to one lable and set "" to the anther lable and then hide it, this works perfectly but I have no idea why!, just had to play around until it worked like this!.